# C# - How many days left in year from Datetime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to get the number of days left in a year from `Datetime.Now`.

Having a little trouble, I tried using a `datediff` without much success.

I don't suppose one of you experts could perhaps show me how this would be achieved in C#?

I'd like a code to return an integer value for the days remaining.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
int daysInYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(date.Year) ? 366 : 365;
int daysLeftInYear = daysInYear - date.DayOfYear; // Result is in range 0-365.
```

Note that it's important to only evaluate `DateTime.Now` *once*, otherwise you could get an inconsistency if it evaluates once at the end of one year and once at the start of another.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Result is in range 0-366 for leap-years.

Comment: @Quandary: No it's not, because DayOfYear is at least 1.

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = new DateTime(now.Year + 1, 1, 1);
int daysLeftInYear = (int)(end - now).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, you could do this:

```
Date someDate = DateTime.Now;
Date nextYear = new DateTime(someDate.Year + 1, 1, 1);
int daysLeft = (nextYear - someDate).Days;
```

Not tested because I'm at home, but I'm pretty sure on the logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    public int DaysLeftInYear()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        int daysInYear = 365;
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(today.Year))
        {
            daysInYear++;
        }

        return daysInYear - today.DayOfYear;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
DateTime EOY = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
int DaysLeft = EOY.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have bigger date (endDate) and you want to know how many days big ,

```
int days = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner, based on top voted answer:

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(DateTime.Today.Year) ? 366 - DateTime.Today.DayOfYear : 365 - DateTime.Today.DayOfYear
```

Answer (score -1):

Already a lot of answers that work, but haven't seen this simple one yet

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
int daysleft = new DateTime(today.Year,12,31).DayOfYear - today.DayOfYear;
```